# Get-WinEvent and Select-string filter line result

Tags: powershell, select-string, get-winevent

I´m trying to use get-winevent + select string to filter and get the IP from events 4625.

After get-winevent I want to filter the results to show only "Source Network Address:" line, which will provide me the list of IP´s I need to block.

Below is an example of the results, thanks in advance!

PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName='Security';ID=4625} -MaxEvents 1 | fl

TimeCreated  : 15/02/2023 07:43:25
ProviderName : Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing
Id           : 4625
Message      : An account failed to log on.

```
           Subject:
            Security ID:            S-1-0-0
            Account Name:           -
            Account Domain:         -
            Logon ID:               0x0

           Logon Type:                      3

           Account For Which Logon Failed:
            Security ID:            S-1-0-0
            Account Name:           ADMINISTRATOR
            Account Domain:

           Failure Information:
            Failure Reason:         Unknown user name or bad password.
            Status:                 0xC000006D
            Sub Status:             0xC0000064

           Process Information:
            Caller Process ID:      0x0
            Caller Process Name:    -

           Network Information:
            Workstation Name:       -
            Source Network Address: 209.45.48.94
            Source Port:            0

           Detailed Authentication Information:
            Logon Process:          NtLmSsp
            Authentication Package: NTLM
            Transited Services:     -
            Package Name (NTLM only):       -
            Key Length:             0
```

Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName='Security';ID=4625} -MaxEvents 100 | Select-String -Pattern "Source Network Address:" tried this way but no results showed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName='Security';ID=4625} -MaxEvents 1).Message.split(':') -split("`t") | ? { $_ -match '\d+\.\d+\.\d+.\d+'} | % {$_ -replace ("`n","")}
```

Comment: Amazing! Worked as expected! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As it seems you need to extract an IP-address, I would suggest to use a regex for matching it.

```
$regex = [regex]::new("\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b")
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName='Security';ID=4625} -MaxEvents 100 | Foreach {$regex.Match($_.Message).Value}
```

This code loops through each result which `Get-WinEvent` returns and checks with the regex for an IP-address in the message property. When no match is found it will return an empty line.

Comment: Amazing! Worked as expected! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To get information from the Windows Event log, it is cumbersome to try and parse that out of the Message string.

Better look at the XML where the values can be found under their own attribute names:

```
$result = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName='Security';ID=4625} -MaxEvents 100 | ForEach-Object {
    # convert the event to XML and grab the Event node
    $eventXml = ([xml]$_.ToXml()).Event
    # output the values from the XML representation
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        UserName  = ($eventXml.EventData.Data | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'TargetUserName' }).'#text'
        IpAddress = ($eventXml.EventData.Data | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'IpAddress' }).'#text'
        EventDate = [DateTime]$eventXml.System.TimeCreated.SystemTime
    }
}
```

Now, if all you want from this is the list of IP addresses, just do

```
$result.IpAddress
```

Comment: Theo Thanks for the example, will try!